# OutputStream is not available when a custom TextWriter is used

Tags: c#, asp.net

this is my function which converts pdf to png image, it's throwing an error on
this line-->  stream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream); Is there some thing wrong??

```
protected void CreatePngFromPdf() 
        {

            try
            {

                string PDFLocation = string.Format(@"\\XXXX\{0}\{1}\{2}.pdf", Yr, Loc.Substring(0, 4), Loc.Substring(4, 4));
                Utilities.WebPDF.PDF WebPDF = new DocuvaultMVC.Utilities.WebPDF.PDF();

                WebPDF.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(@"xyz", "xyz");
                byte[] png = WebPDF.StreamPdfPageAsPngResize(PDFLocation,PageNumber, 612, 792);

                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(png);
                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
                int newWidth = 612;
                int newHeight = 792;
                System.Drawing.Image newImg = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);

                Bitmap temp = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight, newImg.PixelFormat);
                Graphics newImage = Graphics.FromImage(temp);
                newImage.DrawImage(newImg, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
                newImg.Dispose();

                temp.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);
                stream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
                temp.Dispose();
                stream.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Oh my, this is going to leak handles if an exception is thrown :-) You should really consider using `using` when working with disposable resources such as streams and GDI+ objects.

Comment: Pinu, some details on the Exception would help. Also the context where this is called. (ASPX or ASHX, which event?) The code itself is basically OK, except for the comment @Darin makes.

Comment: @Darin , I dint get you , can you give me an example of how i can use this with using?

Comment: @Pinu, what exact exception are you getting? What is `DocuvaultMVC.Utilities.WebPDF`?

Comment: It's  a reference to the webservice that i am using

Comment: But i dont thing there is any thing wrong with that WebService , as some of the other application is using the same code and it works perfectly for that appliction. 

Following is the information on exception:

base {System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException} = {"OutputStream is not available when a custom TextWriter is used."}

Comment: I followed this example and changed the way i was rendering the image and it fixed my error.
Example Link:
http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2008/05/ASPNET-MVC-custom-ActionResult.aspx

Answer (score 47):

This is not directly relevant to your problem, but I got the same exception when doing something else, so I thought I'd put that answer here for posterity...

I got this exception merely when the homepage was rendering, rather than when going to the relevant controller action.

Much head-scratching ensues, until I realise that I've used `Html.Action` (which runs the action and emits the HTML inline) rather than `Url.Action` (which generates the URL).

Comment: Yes! thanks - for anyone who would like to stick with @Html helper - you can also use @Html.ActionLink(xxx)

Answer (score 1):

**In my case the reason was wrong argument in Controller.File method.**

Controller.File method with third parameter as **null** will render the image in the browser window:

```
public ActionResult GenerateImage(...)
{
    ...
    return File(fileResult.Buffer, fileResult.ContentType, null);
}
```

Controller.File method with third parameter as **filename** will trigger downloading of the image in the browser:

```
public ActionResult GenerateImage(...)
{
    ...
    return File(fileResult.Buffer, fileResult.ContentType, "image.jpg");
}
```

Controller.File method with third parameter as **extension** will cause the error: **OutputStream is not available when a custom TextWriter is used**

```
public ActionResult GenerateImage(...)
{
    ...
    return File(fileResult.Buffer, fileResult.ContentType, ".jpg");
}
```