# Url.Action fails to call controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to display some images on a page with this view

**Details.cshtml**

```
@foreach (var imagePath in Model.Images)
{
    <img src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Receiving", new { @imagePath = imagePath })" />
}
```

**ReceivingController.cs**

```
public ActionResult GetImage(string imagePath)
{
    var folder = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImagesPath"];
    var path = Path.Combine(folder, imagePath);
    byte[] image = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
    return File(image, "image/jpg");
}
```

But when I set a breakpoint in the controller, it never gets hit and of course the images fail to load.

I can see the value being passed from the view is a path e.g. `"C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\SiteName\\Images\\3000\\1\\1\\2.jpg"`

I tried changing `@Url.Action' to`@Html.Action` just because I have no idea what else to try, but I got an error

> OutputStream is not available when a custom TextWriter is used

I don't understand why the controller is not being called.

I noticed if I just navigate to the url `Receiving\GetImage\whyareyounotworking`, the controller action is fired.

I tried adding a route as below, but with no change

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "GetImage",
    url: "receiving/GetImage/{imagePath}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Receiving", action = "GetImage" }
);
```

Comment: Why not just set the value of `imagePath` to the correct value - e.g. `"/Images/YourFileName.jpg"`? The issue is that the route contains a `.` (refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728846/dots-in-url-causes-404-with-asp-net-mvc-and-iis))

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have been struggling with this for ages now. The image is sitting in a seperate website/app pool for a site which is only internal. However, this seperate, outward facing site needs to serve the images from the internal site. I am unsure how to build the relative url to do this or if its even possible. Seems it should be such an easy task just to display some images yet I just can't seem to do it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be something to do with the string being passed in.

After removing the `.jpg` from the end of the file path before passing back to the controller my breakpoint now hits.

Answer (score 0):

remove this:

```
@imagePath
```

So you will have an url.action like this:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Receiving", new { imagePath = imagePath })" />
```

Comment: That makes no difference

Comment: this might help you more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776880/outputstream-is-not-available-when-a-custom-textwriter-is-used